# How to average a score in groups based on the month and year in SQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, to-char

I have a table called reviews. Reviews has two columns I care about: score (int) and created_at (datetime).
Imagine the following data

| id | score | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 2022-01-15 |
| 2 | 1 | 2022-01-15 |
| 3 | 2 | 2022-02-01 |
| 4 | 3 | 2022-02-04 |
| 5 | 5 | 2022-03-30 |

I want to return the average score grouped by the month and the year. To get the following result

| date | average_score |
| --- | --- |
| Jan 2022 | 3 |
| Feb 2022 | 2.5 |
| Mar 2022 | 5 |

My current code is below. It is almost working but it isn't grouping by the date and I can't figure out why. Please let me know if I am way off here but I think I am so close I just need the data to group

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(reviews.created_at, 'Mon YYYY') AS date,
       AVG(reviews.score) OVER (PARTITION BY TO_CHAR(reviews.created_at, 'Mon YYYY')) AS average_score
FROM   "reviews"
WHERE  "reviews"."score" IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY date, score
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the window function:

- use the corresponding `AVG` aggregation function
- remove the score from the `GROUP BY` clause
- remove the null scores check, as the aggregation functions skip null values

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(created_at, 'Mon YYYY') AS date,
       AVG(score) AS average_score
FROM   "reviews"
GROUP BY date
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aQgqRZKQuref3cN6DxNuEx/1).

**Note**: in your code the `GROUP BY` clause is doing nothing as long as there's no aggregation function applied to any field called in your `SELECT` clause.

Comment: `where score is not null` is not needed... AVG function skips null values.